# Why do I get an .epub.zip file instead of an .epub one when downloading it on mobile?

Tags: html, attributes

I'm having this issue as described in the title.
So I've made an anchor tag from where I want the users to be able to download an epub file.

On a desktop it downloads fine and it's readable, but on mobile it turns into an .epub.zip file.
Changing the ".epub.zip" into ".zip" makes the file readable, but that is not user friendly.

Here is a sample code:

```
<a class="some-class" href="books/book-name.epub" download="book-name.epub"">EPUB Book</a>
```

I've seen it working on other websites and inspecting the link didn't reveal any use (at all) of the download attribute.

I've even tried (both with and without) to add a download attribute specifying the book title to be downloaded, but it didn't fix the problem (I'm not sure if i'm doing right when using the download attr).

Comment: Perhaps your server or cloud folder is not setting the content-type header properly.  Using f12 tools in a desktop browser might tell you if that is it.

Comment: How should I set that?

Comment: Headers are set by the server not your HTML, so it depends on what the server is.  If it is not your server then you can't change it except possibly if you can change the accept headers sent from the client.

Comment: It's a simple front end website for a book. It's hosted on hostinger on my account.

Comment: `I've seen it working on other websites and inspecting the link ...` try using the network tab in developer tools and looking at the headers sent for your site and the other working site (when the file is downloading) to see if the content-type is the same or different.  I'm just guessing here so the server headers might not be the cause.

Comment: I did as you said and this is what happened:
- My site had no headers when downloading the epub format. I did disable cache as well. The book is also in mobi and pdf format, which does get some headers when trying to download. The download links are similar, and only the book format is different.
- The website where this works, does also have headers where the content type is "application/epub+zip".
Deleting the download attribute does result in getting headers. and the content-type is the same: "application/epub+zip". Still the book is an .epub.zip format.

Comment: Still guessing, but you might check the other headers to see what else is different.

Comment: I'm sorry for the previous reply. 
Idk where I was looking, or maybe I was too tired. 
So my website with the issue has the content-type: text/plain, while on the working website it's application/epub+zip.
Edit: so testing the website on my computer using live server has the content-type as  application/epub+zip, but the hosted one is text/plain

Comment: Are your downloads coming directly from stored files on the server, `/folder/foo.epub` or using a script page that reads the local file and echoes it?  If a script file, you can add the headers in the script.  If a direct file, you might ask your hosting company how to fix the content-type for the files.

Comment: So I have a clone of the website on a free netlify account and I don't get this issue. 
Your comments helped me with troubleshooting and getting to this point, but I'm stuck here now. 
Hostinger recommends making a .htaccess file but i have no idea what to write in it. 

https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583307-how-to-create-an-htaccess-file?fbclid=IwAR28j73fJzvyBFDy30kqBveud8wquOyfy-tqgAoX02Hnd0nK3xGFwYSHPQ4

This is the hostinger link.

Edit: the downloads come from a folder stored in a server.

Comment: Try a search on "how to set content-type in htaccess" and if that fails you can ask a new question like "how do I set 'content-type: application/epub+zip' for epub in htaccess?"

Comment: I'll do that, thank you!

Comment: I've contacted Hostinger (the hosting company) and they helped fix the problem:
Since I started pursuing it here, I'll put the solution to  the iss
I had to add a .htaccess file inside the file folder, with the following contents:
`<FilesMatch "\.(?i:epub)$">
    ForceType application/epub
    Header set Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=%{filename.epub}"
</FilesMatch>`